# referencing 2 cell and count variables of one column

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image]

I am trying to count all P on B2:E16, referencing F2 to A2:A16, by use of countifs  it works but I want to also reference months on f1 to b1:E1 so that it only counts P on the months selected on F1

Comment: Do you mean you want to count B2:D16? You have G16 in your description. Also, how does someone select a month in F1? Is it manually, and is it one month only or can they select multiple months?

Comment: F1 and F2 are manual drop-down list, I want it that when I change from Jan to Feb it counts the values of P on Feb at the table,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A10,F2,INDEX(A2:E10,0,MATCH(F1,A1:E1,0)),"p")
```

---

Another alternative. If you like Excel table objects, you could use this:

1. Select your table.
2. Make it an actual Excel object using "Insert" -> "Table"
3. If your table was given the name "Table1", then the following formula will work:

```
=COUNTIFS(Table1[area],F2,INDEX(Table1,0,MATCH(F1,Table1[#Headers],0)),"p")
```

Comment: thank you very much it worked with both options.